# How do I finalize the main thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading, finalizer

Is there a way to execute a function when the main thread of a python process is shut down (normally or with an uncaught exception)?

I was hoping `atexit.register` would provide that functionality, but apparently it does not get invoked when the *main thread* has terminated - only when *all threads* have terminated. So this code does not work as intended:

```
import atexit
import threading

done = False

def stop_child_thread():
    global done
    done = True

def child_thread():
    while not done:
        pass

atexit.register(stop_child_thread)
t = threading.Thread(target=child_thread)
t.start()
```

I do not want to start the child thread as a daemon thread because I want it to have a chance to clean up after itself before it is terminated.

The only solution I can think of right now is to periodically check (from either the child thread or from a dedicated thread) whether the main thread is still alive, and if not, run the function I need.

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to have another thread `join` the main thread and then do the cleanup:

```
def cleanup_on_main_thread_exit():
    threading.main_thread().join()
    do_whatever()

threading.Thread(target=cleanup_on_main_thread_exit).start()
```

Comment: Thx, this seems to work in the simple setup that I showed in my question - it's better than the polling I was planning to use. Unfortunately, somehow in the actual code, it results in a slight glitch: python interpreter seems to stay alive despite all the threads completing successfully; it is easily stopped by CTRL-C. I'm not sure what's going on, and I can't repro it with a small example; perhaps python interpreter exit mechanism gets confused.